# How to return the lowest 8 values in a table of scores in sql with a particular value included in each result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table '`S3results`:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
| Studentno | Fullname |     Subject      | Fmagg |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
|    100509 | Terry    | Accounts         |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Art              |     6 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Biology          |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Chemistry        |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Commerce         |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Computer Studies |     4 |
|    100509 | Terry    | English          |     6 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Geography        |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | History          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Mathematics      |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Physics          |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Accounts         |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Art              |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Biology          |     5 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Commerce         |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | English          |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Geography        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | History          |     4 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Mathematics      |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Physics          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Accounts         |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Art              |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Biology          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Commerce         |     5 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | English          |     6 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Geography        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | History          |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Mathematics      |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Physics          |     6 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
```

What i want is to select 8 subjects with the lowest scores for each student in the `fmagg` column but English should be included in the results irrespective of their score.

Below is the result I want:

```
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
| Studentno | Fullname |     Subject      | Fmagg |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
|    100509 | Terry    | Accounts         |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Geography        |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | History          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Physics          |     1 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Chemistry        |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Commerce         |     2 |
|    100509 | Terry    | Biology          |     3 |
|    100509 | Terry    | English          |     6 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Art              |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Geography        |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Mathematics      |     1 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Physics          |     2 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Commerce         |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | Computer Studies |     3 |
|    100510 | Sena     | English          |     4 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Art              |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Chemistry        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Geography        |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | History          |     1 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Accounts         |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Biology          |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | Mathematics      |     2 |
|    100511 | Cristen  | English          |     6 |
+-----------+----------+------------------+-------+
```

Some one proposed the solution below:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg,  
        CASE WHEN [Subject] IN ('Mathematics', 'English')
            THEN 0
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Studentno ORDER BY Fmagg ASC)
        END AS Ranking
    FROM S3Results
)
SELECT Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg 
FROM cte
WHERE Ranking < 8
ORDER BY Studentno, Fmagg
```

the above code worked for me until i realized that it's excluding values equal to or greater than 5 unless it's English. for example given a student scored the following: 5,2,3,5,2,3,3,4,7,7,1 running that query will produce: 3,1,2,2,3,3,4. as you can see those are 7 rows and not 8 as i wanted. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (The answer may depend on the product used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Studentno, Fullname, Subject, Fmagg
FROM (
  SELECT Studentno, Fullname, Subject, Fmagg,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Studentno 
                            ORDER BY 
                               CASE 
                                  WHEN Subject = 'English' THEN -1 
                                  ELSE Fmagg 
                               END, 
                               Subject)  AS rn
  FROM S3results) AS t
WHERE t.rn <= 8
ORDER BY Studentno, Fullname, Fmagg, Subject
```

`ROW_NUMBER` will enumerate records within each student partition placing `'English'` subject always on the first place. After that the rest of the subjects will follow in ascending score order.

**Output:**

```
Studentno   Fullname    Subject Fmagg
=====================================
100509      Terry       Accounts    1
100509      Terry       Geography   1
100509      Terry       History     1
100509      Terry       Physics     1
100509      Terry       Chemistry   2
100509      Terry       Commerce    2
100509      Terry       Biology     3
100509      Terry       English     6
100510      Sena        Art         1
100510      Sena        Chemistry   1
100510      Sena        Geography   1
100510      Sena        Mathematics 1
100510      Sena        Physics     2
100510      Sena        Commerce    3
100510      Sena        Computer Studies    3
100510      Sena        English     4
100511      Cristen     Art         1
100511      Cristen     Chemistry   1
100511      Cristen     Geography   1
100511      Cristen     History     1
100511      Cristen     Accounts    2
100511      Cristen     Biology     2
100511      Cristen     Mathematics 2
100511      Cristen     English     6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting 7 results instead of 8 because the query excludes subjects with a ranking of 8 or more. If you changed the query to use <= instead of a < (as below) then the 8th subject will also be returned:

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg,  
CASE WHEN [Subject] IN ('English')
THEN 0
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Studentno ORDER BY Fmagg ASC)
END AS Ranking
FROM    S3Results)

SELECT  Studentno, Fullname, [Subject], Fmagg 
FROM    cte
WHERE   Ranking <= 8
ORDER BY Studentno,Fmagg
```

Comment: i tried that before and it returned some with 9 results yet i want only 8

Comment: I've updated the answer to remove Mathematics as being a subject that should always be included. Previously if Mathematics was not one of the lowest 8 then you would get 9 results. This should now work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  b.Studentno, b.Fullname, b.Subject, b.Fmagg
from
  (
    select
      row_number() over(partition by c.Studentno
        order by
          case when c.Subject = 'English'
               then 0
               else c.Fmagg
          end asc) rn
      ,c.Studentno
      ,c.Subject
      ,c.Fullname
      ,c.Fmagg
    from
      S3results c
  ) as b
where
  b.rn <= 8
order by
  b.Studentno, b.Fullname, b.Fmagg
```